# Python Beautiful Soup Scraping Specific Numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A much simpler question...

Using the code below how do I scrape the HTML tags so the result is just a number?

I'm using a different webpage.

```
import pickle
import math
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

favPrevGMInfoUrl = 'http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/gametracker/boxscore/NFL_20140914_NE@MIN'
favPrevGMInfoHtml = urlopen(favPrevGMInfoUrl).read()
favPrevGMInfoSoup = BeautifulSoup(favPrevGMInfoHtml)
favPrevGMInfo = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find_all("td", { "id" : "away-safeties" })

print favPrevGMInfo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last print statement to -

```
print favPrevGMInfo[0].text
```

or change the line above to -

```
favPrevGMInfo = favPrevGMInfoSoup.find("td", { "id" : "away-safeties" }).text
```

Answer (score 1):

This site is not returning the source in the get request of the original url rather via a ajax json call - http://www.nfl.com/feeds-rs/videos/byGameCenter/2014091404.json?gameState=POST&maxResult=0&random=1434035648930.

You will need to fetch the data from this call. Please use Network tab to analuse all requests being made.

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't know how to do that so I'm using a different webpage. The new webpage has an "id" tag attached to every number, as a result it's much easier. I just need help striping the HTML from the answer.